# My main function does not allow me to enter any input and crashes after a while

Tags: arrays, c, function, loops

Basically the program is supposed to allow me to test the words . I am trying learn how to add multiple functions inside the main function but for some reason , I couldn't run the program . Could I know where is my mistake or how can I work on the program .

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

void read_word(int counts[26]);
bool equal_array(int counts1[26] , int counts2[26]);

int main (void)
{
    int counts1[26] = {0} , counts2[26] = {0} ;


    read_word(counts1);
    read_word(counts2);

    if(equal_array(counts1, counts2)){
        printf("The words are not anagrams");
    }
    else{
        printf("The words are anagrams");
    }   
    
    return 0;
  
}
void read_word(int counts[26])
{
    char ch , alphabet ;
    printf("Enter word: ");
    //initialise the letters array first and assign all of them value of 0 
    for(alphabet = 'a' ; alphabet <= 'z'; alphabet++){
        counts[alphabet] = 0;
    }
    //first loop to get the word and num
    while ((ch = getchar()) != '\n')
    {
        if (isalpha(ch))
        {
            counts[tolower(ch)]++;
        }
        counts[ch]++; //Is this statement needed ? why ?
    }
}
bool equal_array(int counts1[26] , int counts2[26])
{

    char alphabet;
    //third loop to check the whole array
    for (alphabet = 'a' ; alphabet <= 'z'; alphabet++)
    {
        if (counts1[alphabet] != counts2[alphabet])
        {
            return true ;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
        
    }


}
```

Comment: _//initialise the letters array first and assign all of them value of 0_ this is not required , which is already done by `int counts1[26] = {0} , counts2[26] = {0} ;` in `main` function

Comment: See [ASCII Table and Description](http://www.asciitable.com/) and look at the decimal value for the ASCII characters `'a'` and `'z'`... (hint: `counts[97]` through `counts[122]` invokes *Undefined Behavior* by writing beyond the bounds of your array). Perhaps you want to set `counts[alphabet - 'a'] = 0;` ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned above in the comment, the ASCII value for `'a'` is `97` and `122` for `'z'`. When you attempt to iterate:

```
    for(alphabet = 'a' ; alphabet <= 'z'; alphabet++){
        counts[alphabet] = 0;
    }
```

You access elements well beyond the end of your array -- invoking *Undefined Behavior*. See [ASCII Table & Description](http://www.asciitable.com/). The irony (as also mentioned in the comment) is the loop is entirely unnecessary because your declaration and initialization of your arrays already set each element in the arrays to zero:

```
    int counts1[26] = {0} , counts2[26] = {0};
```

While not an error, passing the arrays as, e.g. `void read_word(int counts[26]);`, shows a misconception of how arrays are treated on access. On access, an array is converted to a pointer to its first elements. This is known as *Array / Pointer Conversion* and it is set forth in the standard at [C11 Standard - 6.3.2.1 Other Operands - Lvalues, arrays, and function designators(p3)](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.2.1p3). What this means is you simply need to provide a pointer as the parameter to represent your arrays in the function arguments, e.g.

```
void read_word (int *counts);
bool equal_array (int *counts1, int *counts2);
```

**Don't Hardcode Filenames or Use Magic Numbers in Your Code**

When you write code, you don't want to sprinkle *Magic Numbers* (e.g. `26`) or hardcode filenames. Instead, if you need a constant, `#define` one or use a global `enum` for the same purpose:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

#define ALPHA 26        /* if you need a constant, #define one (or more) */
...
int main (void)
{
    int counts1[ALPHA] = {0},
        counts2[ALPHA] = {0};
```

Why? If you need to make changes later to the value, you don't have to go picking through each array declaration or loop limit to make changes. You have one single convenient location up top to make the change and it is automatically applied throughout your code.

If you need to pass a filename to your program, pass it as an argument to `main()` (that's what `int argc, char **argv` are for) or take input from the user. Why? You shouldn't have to recompile your program just to read from a different filename.

**Match Your Variable Type to Function Return Type**

Declaring `char ch;` and then assigning `ch = getchar();` is not right. Why? What is the declaration for `getchar()`? See [man 3 getchar](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getchar.3.html). How is it declared and what does it return?

```
int getchar(void);
```

The function returns `int` not `char`, so you must declare `int ch;` instead of `char ch;`. It also allows you to validly check `if (ch == EOF)`.

**Your `read_word()` Function**

When you are reading with `getchar()`, in addition to checking for `'\n'`, you must also check for `EOF`. There is no guarantee your line will end with `'\n'`. The user may very well generate a manual `EOF` with <kbd>Ctrl + d</kbd> (or <kbd>Ctrl + z</kbd> on windows). Therefore your loop should be:

```
void read_word (int *counts)
{
    int ch;             /* ch must be int to match getchar() and catch EOF */
    
    fputs ("Enter word: ", stdout);
    
    while ((ch = getchar()) != '\n' && ch != EOF)       /* loop over each char in line */
    {
        if (isalpha(ch))
        {
            counts[tolower(ch) - 'a']++;                /* map to zero-based index */
        }
        // counts[ch]++; //Is this statement needed ? why ?
        // no - only alpha chars are counted
    }
}
```

**Note:** `tolower()` returns lower-case *character* (e.g. the ASCII value for the lower-case character). Therefore to map the character back to your Zero-Based array index, you must subtract `'a'` from the return.

**Give Your Functions Names With Plain Meaning**

Your `equal_array()` function returns `true` if the arrays `counts1` and `counts2` are NOT equal and returns `false` if the ARE equal. That is directly opposite of what `equal_arrays` means. Instead, you could do:

```
bool equal_array (int *counts1, int *counts2)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < ALPHA; i++)
        if (counts1[i] != counts2[i])
            return false;

    return true;
}
```

(**note:** there is never the need for an `else` if all that happens is a `return`)

Putting it altogether you would have:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

#define ALPHA 26        /* if you need a constant, #define one (or more) */

void read_word (int *counts);
bool equal_array (int *counts1, int *counts2);

int main (void)
{
    int counts1[ALPHA] = {0},
        counts2[ALPHA] = {0};

    read_word(counts1);
    read_word(counts2);

    if (equal_array(counts1, counts2))
        puts ("The words are anagrams");
    else 
        puts ("The words are not anagrams");
    
    return 0;
  
}
void read_word (int *counts)
{
    int ch;             /* ch must be int to match getchar() and catch EOF */
    
    fputs ("Enter word: ", stdout);
    
    while ((ch = getchar()) != '\n' && ch != EOF)       /* loop over each char in line */
    {
        if (isalpha(ch))
        {
            counts[tolower(ch) - 'a']++;                /* map to zero-based index */
        }
        // counts[ch]++; //Is this statement needed ? why ?
        // no - only alpha chars are counted
    }
}

bool equal_array (int *counts1, int *counts2)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < ALPHA; i++)
        if (counts1[i] != counts2[i])
            return false;

    return true;
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/isanagram
Enter word: anagram
Enter word: nag a ram
The words are anagrams
```

or

```
$ ./bin/isanagram
Enter word: anagram
Enter word: nag a ham
The words are not anagrams
```

Now it is working as it should. Let me know if you have any further questions.